# Step type correlation plot: Need to understand correlation between 2 variables

Tags: correlation, cross-correlation

I am struggling analyzing the correlation between two variables in my experiments. It turns out that I now that when the SNR of the signal (the definition of the signal with respect to the noise) is high, the algorithm gives a better score. However, from the SNR-Score plot, I cannot see that relationship or at least it is not so evident.

What do you do when you have a correlation plot such as this?

[image]

I can see two clusters, and the cluster below is because some configuration of the experiment produced that results. but the rest seems to be a plateau not a linear regression model and the R2 is almost 0.

What kind of information could we extract from here?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide more details about your experiment and what you have plotted in this figure.

Comment: welll, my experiment is a computational neuroscience experiment where I run an algorithm to detect brain rhythms from the  electrodes in the brain. I get the reference and output classes for the experiment and I perform a scoring process from the precision, recall, etc. Then I plot the Signal to noise ratio and the score, which is the information in the plot.